# How do I get a parameter value from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

Tags: php, laravel, http-referer

In a PHP application, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] has the following value:

```
http://testing.localhost/userdashboard/test/fc
```

I have try this `$value= striurl($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'test');`, the value I get is `test/fc`.

My question is what is the proper way to extract the value of "fc"?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Did you want get only fc  value from url ??

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's `Request` class has a function called `segments()` which returns an array of all segments in the url.

here it would be = to `['userdashboard', 'test', 'fc']`

So with that in mind, you can grab the last piece with...

```
$lastSegment = last(request()->segments());
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo end(explode("/",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

```
$base = basename('test/fc');
echo $base;  // fc
```

You might also want to look at [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which will extract all the elements of a URL into a nice array structure.